# Async feed refresh in Rails application

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I am working on a rails4 application in which I want to automatically refresh the feed and prepend new posts on the top of the feed after fixed internal.
Currently I am thinking of using JQuery's `setInterval()` function to make a ajax request after say 2 minutes to fetch new posts and prepend to news feed. But I am concerned about the load it will cause for the server.

Is there any other way for building same functionality with better performance?

Answer (score 0):

setInterval() is a fine way to go, unless you want to implement some sort of socket/firebase implementation.

If you are really worried about load, you can use techniques to limit the load. For example, in the request you can pass along the timestamp for the newest post currently loaded, and in the controller only query if there are newer posts and only send back those newer posts.